# Need to update DNS response packet

Tags: c++, networking, dns, udp

I want to update the DNS response packet, specifically RDATA with my own IP address.
I am able to parse DNS response and reach to data_len and next four bytes  I am updating it with IP address and rewrite to the network stack but it is not accepting the response and it keeps trying to resolve the IP address. Below is the code snippet which I tried.

```
            *(current) =  106;
            *(current + 1) =  10;
            *(current + 2) =  250;
            *(current + 3) =  11;
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong with the code you have shown?

Comment: Since I am new to this, I am not sure, Is it a correct way or not. Also, when I am updating it and sending to the network stack, it is not redirected further and keep resolving the IP address that means something is wrong.

Comment: The code you show does not look wrong by itself.  But it is taken too much out of any context which means that the correctness cannot properly be evaluated. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) on what is expected in a good question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I follow http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch15/#rdata to parse the DNS response. My actual intention here is to replace DNS response IP address to my own IP. (current) pointer basically showing the starting point of RDATA. My ask here is to understand if anything else requires to update DNS answer section since the above changes not accepted my network stack.

Comment: You need to expand "network stack but it is not accepting the response" what does that mean precisely? Did you check with a network sniffer how the packet comes back exactly? If you are not doing this to learn, there are probably simplest way to change your ip address, by configuring things differently or use something like `dnsmasq`.